# additional menu in a content box

Tags: html, css

I'm sorry if my problem is already explained somewhere, but I have no idea how actually call it / define my problem for search.

Im "drawing" a homepage in html5 and it works well. I've got my menu on top an it navigates me on the page (like `index.html#abc`). In one of those content boxes I want to have an additional menu inside the box. I want to load the content depending on what I've chosen / clicked there. I was thinking about including the content with php, but I don't have experience with html5 and php - so don't know if that's even possible.

```
__________
|Menu #1 #2# 3#
______
|#1
______
|#2
______
|#3
|submenu (#a #b #c)
|content=a (or b/c if i click on that
_________
```

I'm a newbie! sorry!

Comment: Optionally you can use this in your sections: https://jqueryui.com/tabs/

Answer (score 0):

If you want to dynamically load content, you may need ajax.

Here is some documentation:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ajax_%28programming%29

And ajax made simple with the JQuery javascript librabry:
http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/

Answer (score 0):

> I wanna load the content depending on what I've chosen / clicked there. I was thinking about to include the content with php...

Well... You can SIMULATE this using a combination of PHP and Javascript but you need to understand something:

**All PHP code is executed before the page is delivered to the browser.**

This is because the PHP code runs on the server, before the HTML and CSS are sent to the user's browser. When a user goes to your site and accesses a php file with the following line:

```
<div id="title"><?php echo "Sam's Sick Beats"; ?></div>
```

Her computer will ONLY receive the resulting HTML:

```
<div id="title">Sam's Sick Beats</div>
```

Given this, you can't technically "load the content using PHP depending on what is chosen" because PHP will have finished executing by the time they choose anything. You do have a couple options though...

**Option 1: Add all the information you're ever going to need to the page before it loads and only show what's necessary using Javascript.**

Say you have 3 menu options with 3 choices inside each and you'd like each of the 9 choices to show different content. You could do something like the following:

```
<div id="content_frame">

<?php for ($i = 0; $i < 3; $i++)
{
    for ($i2 = 0; $i2 < 3; $i2++)
    { ?>

        <div id="<?php echo $i . '_' . $i2; ?>">Here is content for the <?php echo $i . ' -> ' . $i2; ?> menu selection.</div>

<?php }
} ?>

</div>
```

The resulting HTML will look like this:

```
<div id="content_frame">
    <div id="0_1">Here is content for the 0 -> 1 menu selection.</div>
    <div id="0_2">Here is content for the 0 -> 2 menu selection.</div>
    <div id="0_3">Here is content for the 0 -> 3 menu selection.</div>
    <div id="1_1">Here is content for the 1 -> 1 menu selection.</div>
    <div id="1_2">Here is content for the 1 -> 2 menu selection.</div>
    <div id="1_3">Here is content for the 1 -> 3 menu selection.</div>
    <div id="2_1">Here is content for the 2 -> 1 menu selection.</div>
    <div id="2_2">Here is content for the 2 -> 2 menu selection.</div>
    <div id="2_3">Here is content for the 2 -> 3 menu selection.</div>
</div>
```

Then use Javascript to add `display: block` and `display: none` to the DIVs using their IDs as menu items are being selected.

**Option 2: Use AJAX to load the information on the fly.**

AJAX is a pretty tough hill to climb for a beginner and it doesn't seem necessary in your case. You would only need it in situations such as if the content was being pulled dynamically (like you had an input box where people could search for articles from your site) or if content needed to be updated without refreshing the page. Then you'd have to basically fetch the information based on their input and update your HTML with the results of the AJAX call using Javascript.